# Android JSON passing

Tags: android, json

This is my JSON file:

```
{"posts":[{"id":"1","message":"message1","details":"5"},{"id":"3","message":"message2","details":"21"}]}
```

I want to display "message" and "details" in Android application where "id=1". How should I do it?  How should I pass the id parameter to JSON file from my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of links that helped me using JSON:

http://www.hdelossantos.com/2009/12/24/quick-and-easy-android-http-post-of-json-string/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very quick and easy example

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_JSON_Parser_Example

See if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your string with [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) into Java objects. It is one of the fastest ways of parsing JSON. After that you can store them in a database or your own objects.